# A use of 'voir' + infinitive

Tags: infinitif

I came upon this sentence in Jacques Perret's story 'Trafic de Chevaux' (1951):

> ... on s'étonnait fort de voir confier de si fiers palefrois à la plus indescriptible andouille de l'Empire Britannique ...

and notice the lack of a subject for the infinitive *confier*. Is this construction (with the subject of the infinitive only implied) very common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This construction is common.

> *J'ai vu tirer sur la foule.*
> *J'ai vu battre le blé noir au fléau et traire à la main des vaches qu'on attelait au joug pour tirer la charrue.* ([Denis Trinillac](https://www.recyclivre.com/products/224678-paysans-de-france-1770-1970-deux-siecles-d-histoire-de-nos-campagnes))
> *J'entends chanter la Marseillaise.*  (technically ambiguous: *J'entends chanter ma voisine* !)

*Confier* is a complement of *voir*, it has no subject indeed.

Who performs/performed the action is not relevant in the sentence which could have been written, without any substantial change in meaning :

> *[...] on s'étonnait fort de voir de si fiers palefrois confiés à la plus indescriptible andouille de l'Empire Britannique [...]*